# Inputting variable name into functions

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to Go, and I'd like to make this snippet into a function.

Basically, I would like to know if there is a possible way to pass a variable name into a function call so if I called:

`changeColor(varName)`

It would run, and then assign a new value to the original variable, which was inputted into the function call.

Hopefully this makes sense, and thanks in advance

```
if varName == yellow {
    varName = black
} else {
    varName = yellow
}
```

Comment: you can do that using pointers. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: This seems like it would be well covered in the basic docs. You should probably start here first: https://golang.org/doc/

Comment: As the docs can be a bit steep for a newbie this is a pretty simple and comprehensive text about the basics of using Go: https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/8

Comment: @Snowman: Please be careful when editing questions, that you don't change the meaning of the question. (This includes question titles.)

Comment: In a real Go program I'd prefer returning values from functions. Especially since Go can return multiple return values. Then this would look like `color = changeColor(color)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can learn about the concept in general by reading up on different [Evaluation Strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) that programming languages employ. In Go you can achieve the behavior you are looking for with pointers.

Without pointers you are usually passing around copies of your variable. With pointers, you are passing a copy of the *location* of the value in memory. This means the function can then modify the actual value at the location is has learned about.

Here is an example that does what you explained:

http://play.golang.org/p/ufrEjmXwmB

Keep in mind this is probably not the best way to do this in a real program. If the point is to just learn though, then go for it. Try playing around with passing pointers to pointers and so on :p

Comment: Sorry to get into semantics on a beginner question like this, but since "passing by reference" isn't well defined (except in languages like C++ with  something called "references"), most of us prefer to avoid that term for Go. Everything in go is pass by value, including pointers, where the pointer *value* is copied into the argument variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @JimB. I've updated my answer to have more correct language. To my knowledge though, "pass by reference" is well defined in traditional comp-sci text books, though I I did indeed use it incorrectly here. If the answer still look off, feel free to edit, I won't be offended :p

Comment: Yes, maybe the term is well defined in the academic sense, but colloquially it's often incorrectly used (for example, just look at the wiki article you linked under "call by sharing" which lists ruby counter to the community claims of it being "pass-by-reference").